# Empty MySQLi prepared statement results

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm just trying to select a specific row in the DB, but my result-set keeps coming up empty for some reason. However, when I run the query in HeidiSQL, I get results.

I'm stumped. I don't see anything particularly wrong with my code, and I've tried echoing `$mysqli->error`, but I don't have any errors. I have also added `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to my code.

```
$id =$_GET['sysid'];
$system_info = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM systems WHERE systems.id = ?");
$system_info->bind_param("i", $id);
$system_info->execute();
$system_info->store_result();
$system_info->bind_result($system_id, $system_name, $system_img);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) the results.

```
$id = $_GET['sysid'];
$system_info = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM systems WHERE systems.id = ?");
$system_info->bind_param("i", $id);
$system_info->execute();
$system_info->bind_result($system_id, $system_name, $system_img);
$system_info->fetch();
```

Then you can use `$system_id`, `$system_name` and `$system_img`.

[`store_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) will return you a [`mysqli_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object; it ignores `bind_result`.

```
$id = $_GET['sysid'];
$system_info = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM systems WHERE systems.id = ?");
$system_info->bind_param("i", $id);
$system_info->execute();
$result = $system_info->store_result();
list($system_id, $system_name, $system_img) = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Comment: Oh my god. I think I need a break.